# How to add janus graph imports to gremlin groovy script engine?

Tags: groovy, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I use GremlinGroovyScriptEngine, which is part of gremlin-server to evaluate string gremlin queries - like this:

```
final ScriptEngine engine = new GremlinGroovyScriptEngine();
engine.eval("g.V().count().next();");
```

... everything was good until I have started to use janus-graph specific elements in queries - like that (last string):

```
final ScriptEngine engine = new GremlinGroovyScriptEngine();

//== Set binding with traversal/graph/transaction to script engine ===
JanusGraphManagement mgmt = jg.openManagement();
SimpleBindings trBinding = new SimpleBindings();
trBinding.putAll(this.bindings);
trBinding.put("mgmt", mgmt);
engine.setBindings(trBinding, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

result = engine.eval("mgmt.makePropertyKey('zzzzzz').dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();");
```

... in that case I got:

```
MissingPropertyException: No such property: SINGLE for class: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty$Cardinality
```

As workaround I define whole class name `org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE` in query.

As I understand it is possible to set up all specific import to script engine during its creation.
Janus specific imports is defined in [JanusGraphGremlinPlugin](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-all/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/graphdb/tinkerpop/plugin/JanusGraphGremlinPlugin.java) class which I use during gremlin-script-engine initialization in this way:

```
JanusGraphGremlinPlugin graphGremlinPlugin = JanusGraphGremlinPlugin.instance();
        
GremlinScriptEngineManager engineManager = new CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager();

/* Create gremlin script engine */
GremlinGroovyScriptEngine engine = GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.class
.cast(engineManager.getEngineByName("gremlin-groovy"));
```

... but it does not work. It seems that `engineManager` not set any plugins because after creation of engine `engine.getPlugins().size()` gives 0.

Also there is direct method of engine for loading plugin:

```
...
 engine.loadPlugins(Collections.singletonList(graphGremlinPlugin))
...
```

... but it receive `List` of instances of `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.GremlinPlugin` class which is deprecated (replaced by `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.GremlinPlugin`).
Moreover [JanusGraphGremlinPlugin](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-all/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/graphdb/tinkerpop/plugin/JanusGraphGremlinPlugin.java) class is descendant of `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.AbstractGremlinPlugin` so that it cannot be used in `.loadPlugins()` method.

Do you know how it is possible to use JanusGraphGremlinPlugin class to add janus-specific imports to gremlin-groovy-engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the plugin to the `GremlinScriptEngineManager` instance:

```
GremlinScriptEngineManager engineManager = new CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager();
engineManager.addPlugin(JanusGraphGremlinPlugin.instance())
engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("gremlin-groovy")
```

As long as the plugin is added before you instantiate the engine, it should work.

Comment: What maven dependency should I define to get `JanusGraphGremlinPlugin` which is descendant of `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.AbstractGremlinPlugin`?

https://javalibs.com/artifact/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-all gives old `org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.plugin.JanusGraphGremlinPlugin` class

Comment: hmm - looks like JanusGraph doesn't support the new plugin system on 0.2.0. you would have to build your own version of JanusGraph at this point - the code has at least changed on master: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/commit/d022f14058a7956e960d72b944408f5eb35d26cb#diff-d06cfe90e184f6fe0cade007f40b65fe if you are stuck on 0.2.0 then you would have to use the old deprecated methods that you've already found to make this all work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarification)